# how to update question on your google assistant trivia

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

i made a google assistant action using template now i want to add more how question to it how can it be done?

Comment: Develop your question, share code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add questions and other required data in sheet from the console and then it will ask you for update test or update prod. You can go for the update prod.